# SQL Server 2008: Snapshot backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to convert an unsynchronized snapshot to a writable database? I'd like to take a production snapshot, copy it to a separate server, and make it available to developers for testing. However, it would need to be writable. Any options?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not just back up the database then restore it to the development server?  That's as good as a snapshot, since it represents the DB at a point in time.

Comment: The DB is currently about 1TB. I'm not sure how practical copying it for testing would be for multiple developers to have their own testing  environment. Not sure snapshots would be any better or possible for that matter.